# Spring actuator health down but all groups are up

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator

So as the title says. Running `/actuator/health` returns down, meanwhile individually checking each groups returns UP.

What could be the cause?

```
$ curl localhost:10010/actuator/health
{"status":"DOWN","groups":["liveness","readiness"]}
$ curl localhost:10010/actuator/health/liveness
{"status":"UP"}
$ curl localhost:10010/actuator/health/readiness
{"status":"UP"}
```

Also as a suspicion of something being odd is that `actuator/health/probes` or `/actuator/health/ping` have an empty response.

Answer (score 0):

To have more details witch service can produce this kind of result `"status":"DOWN"` you should change the default value for next ones properties something like this in your `application.properties/yml` :

`management.health.defaults.enabled=false`

`management.endpoint.health.show-details=always`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We'd checked both properties. But show-details was not much helpful. And comments around the web mention disabling the defaults renders actuator kind of pointless.

Comment: By the way, have you tried to disable default’s health endpoints ? The result has changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Our problem was with AMQ.

```
management.health.jms.enabled: false
```

Solved it for us. What I still do not grasp is why actuator won't list the probes it's checking; Even with show-details.